# Connect to Google SQL from Google App Engine using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to my database from google cloud sql
using hibernate, but I get the following error...

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver
```

but I have the dependency in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
     <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>
```

I call createEntityManagerFactory this way...

```
    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver",
            "com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url",
            System.getProperty("cloudsql.url"));

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
            "Test", properties);
```

Could someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put following into `appengine-web.xml`:

```
<use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
```

Comment: make sure it's declared on deployed version too

Comment: I resolved by changing the version of hibernate. Now I am using 4.2.0.Final and it works.